# DOMCrawler plain text

Tags: php, html, symfony, xpath

I am using Symfony's DomCrawler to fetch an information from website.
In one of the pages there is a text including non-html-encoded attributes like following :

```
<a href="some-url.html">Lorem ipsum <<dolor sit>> amet </a>
```

And when I try to crawl the text from the a tag using the `filterXPath` method I get `Lorem ipsum <`, because as I suppose it behaves to symbols like broken html tags and simply ignores them.

Also, when i try to use `$node->filterXPath('my-xpath/a')->html()`, I also get broken html like following example :

```
<a href="some-url.html">Lorem ipsum &gt;</a>
```

So, my question is if there is any way to get the "plain" text out of the node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this issue on GitHub, it appears that there is no solution for 'fixing' my problem. The only workaround is to fix the broken html.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for can be accomplished by using:

`$node->filterXPath('my-xpath/a')->text();`

You can find documentation on the [Symfony DOM Crawler documentation site](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_text).

Comment: Thank you for Your response, it seems I forgot to mention that the `$node->text()` method also returns a broken html. In my case it just returns `Lorem Ipsum <`

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is if there is any way to get the "plain" text out of the node ?

Yes there is, but you need to fix the HTML first. You don't need to do that by hand by the way, the [HTML tidy extension](http://php.net/tidy) does perfectly deal with your case automatically.

Just *tidy* the HTML before you crawl it.

Comment: Thank you for Your reply, but it won't work in my case, because as I stated in the description, I am using symfony's DOMCrawler module, and when I fetch the page, it is already 'fixed'.

Comment: Also, if you say to fix the source (the website where the data is crawling from), than it won't be a solution either, because the site is not mine, and I just write an application for it to crawl announcements from there and show where it was fetched from (no copyright problem here ;) ), and if I just try to send feedback them for fixing the issue, there will be no point because the site itself is not maintained for a long time and contains tons of bugs...

Comment: You can fix the source the moment you load it in. Not on their server, but when you do the parsing. For example with the ***tidy*** extension I named. I gave it a try it deals *easily* with your case the way you ask for it. You find it linked in the answer. -- Sorry if that was not clear from the answer already. Let me know if you still run into an issue or how I could make this more clear in the answer.